# error in published API The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid when i publish the API in server

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework, oracle11g

I'm using entity framework and oracle connection in API which is running well locally but on IIS server it returns error:

> {"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The
>   specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is
>   not valid.","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":" 
>   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String
>   providerString)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String
>   newConnectionString)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String
>   connectionString)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings
>   appConfigConnection)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String
>   name, AppConfig config)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()\r\n
>   at System.Linq.Queryable.Join[TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult](IQueryable`1
>   outer, IEnumerable`1 inner, Expression`1 outerKeySelector,
>   Expression`1 innerKeySelector, Expression`1 resultSelector)\r\n   at
>   High_Levels.Controllers.TaskController.Tasks(Int32 userId, Int32
>   roleId) in
>   C:\Users\RabeeA\Desktop\Back\High_Levels\Controllers\TaskController.cs:line
>   0\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"$id":"2","Message":"An
>   error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Unable to find the requested
>   .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be
>   installed.","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":" 
>   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String
>   providerInvariantName)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String
>   providerString)"}}

My web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <identity impersonate="false" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="EB42632606E9261F" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
            </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <!--<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WF_Entities" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=TestDB2;PASSWORD=wf_engine123;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=WF_ENGINE" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />

    <add name="HL_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.HL_Model.csdl|res://*/Models.HL_Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.HL_Model.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=TestDB2;PASSWORD=high_levels123;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=HIGH_LEVELS&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>-->
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v13.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <!--<providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>-->
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="HL_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.HL_Model.csdl|res://*/Models.HL_Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.HL_Model.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=TestDB2;PASSWORD=high_levels123;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=HIGH_LEVELS&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />-->
    <add name="HL_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.HL_Model.csdl|res://*/Models.HL_Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.HL_Model.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=TestDB2;PASSWORD=high_levels123;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=HIGH_LEVELS&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST,OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>


  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: you have not mentioned the server name, port etc. in the connection string which looks like you are expected to use a DSN

Comment: I'm using iis server ...